# How can I switch between graphic drivers?

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, graphics, laptop, intel-graphics

I'm using Arch linux and I have got two video cards in a laptop without an external monitor. Video cards are intel and nvidia 720M. Intel is used by default and nvidia drivers are installed (I think). Here is the output from `inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.2 driver: modesetting
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.06hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.1
```

And here is the output from `egrep 'EE|WW' /var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[    23.642] Current Operating System: Linux redshift 4.10.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 13 17:13:41 CET 2017 x86_64
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    23.864] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/" does not exist.
[    23.865] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/".
[    23.865] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/".
[    23.902] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[    24.296] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module intel
[    24.296] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
[    24.318] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    24.318] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    24.318] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[    24.318] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[    24.319] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[    24.319] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[    24.351] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
```

How do I use nvidia as my default video card? I use xfce as my desktop, if that's relevant.

Comment: There is no nvidia-driver.

Comment: Not sure how it works in Arch linux, but in general, you can create/edit an `xorg.conf` to force the default drivers and card you want. Usually the location is `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, google and `man Xorg`, `man xorg.conf` etc. for details.

Comment: @bahamut, there are 2 NVIDIA drivers... One from NVIDIA and the open source alternatieve nouveau.